# Convert number to hours

Tags: trigger

I have tried to convert number to hours but I didn't get correct answer. I don't know how to do that.

Here is my code:

```
trigger TimeResult on Case (before insert) {

    Decimal result;
    String strResult;
    String store;
    Decimal rdn;

    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        for(Case timeCase : Trigger.new){
            result = timeCase.Time1__c + timeCase.Time2__c;
            strResult = String.valueOf(result);
            store = string.valueof(strResult).right(2);
            Decimal storePartOne = (Decimal.Valueof(store)/60);
            rdn = Math.Round(storePartOne);
            String resultString = String.valueOf(result).LEFT(1);
            //String resultString = String.valueOf(result);

            Decimal convertResult  = Decimal.Valueof(resultString);
            Decimal finalResult = storePartOne + convertResult;

            timeCase.TimeResult__c = finalResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Here Time1__c,Time2__c,TimeResult__c  is number field. For example 
If i add 1.40 and 1.30 means result is 2.70 but i need in hours like 3 hours 10 mins.

Comment: Pls include some more information. What kind of data is in the Time1 and Time2 fields? And what do you expect in the TimeResult field?

Comment: If i add 1.40 and 1.30 means result is 2.70 but i need in hours like 3 hours 10 mins.

Comment: a silly stupid oneliner that should work for your case: `finalResult = (finalResult - Math.floor(finalResult)<.60 ? finalResult : finalResult + 0.4);`. However, you would be better using `DateTime` class as Itai Shmida posted in his answer

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you are not using a formula field for this?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use Datetime field and use Methods like addHours and addMinutes to handle calculations:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm
Then your data is always a time and you can display it nice.